# How to access a Phaser Texture's ImageData

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework, getimagedata

How can I access the raw ImageData for a Phaser Texture instance?

I've preloaded an image:

```js
thisScene.load.image('my-image', '/path/to/image.jpg')
```

I've created an Image GameObject of that texture:

```js
let myImg = new Phaser.GameObjects.Image(thisScene, 0, 0, 'my-image')
```

Now I want the raw [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData), the "`Uint8ClampedArray` representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (inclusive)."

I know I can get it by *copying* the image into a new Phaser `CanvasTexture`, like so:

```js
let originalTextureSrcImg = thisScene.textures.get('my-image').getSourceImage()

let newTexture = thisScene.textures.createCanvas(
  'copy-of-image',
  originalTextureSrcImg.width, originalTextureSrcImg.height
)

let context = newTexture.getSourceImage().getContext('2d')

context.drawImage(
  originalTextureSrcImg,
  0, 0
)

let imageData = context.getImageData(
  0, 0,
  originalTextureSrcImg.width, originalTextureSrcImg.height
)
```

But that has two drawbacks:

- it seems crude and inefficient, and
- if I want to do this repeatedly and often (at runtime), I'd need to invent some scheme to hold onto some of these intermediary objects that I have no real interest in.

[The documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.Texture.html#source__anchor) (which is surprisingly terrible for how much of it there is), says that a `Texture`'s `.texture` has a `.source` property which is an array of `Phaser.Textures.TextureSource` items, which "contain the actual Image (or Canvas) data," but that wording is deceptive: it's just a repeated set of references to Phaser's own intermediary Texture and Canvas objects: it does not appear to contain a proper `ImageData` anywhere, which makes it worthless for my purposes.

I'm looking for the most-efficient and cleanest *Phaser-idiomatic* way to access the ImageData (in a read-write way) for a Phaser Texture, which is what I'll have natural ways to access.

Comment: Why not use WebGL, Unity?

Answer (score 0):

note: for documentation, try using [notes of phaser 3](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/) instead, its a lot clearer an easyer to understand. For further phaser 3 questions, try the [html5 game devs](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/) forum, they have a much more active phaser 3 community

you can load a texture using

```
var rt = scene.add.renderTexture(x, y, undefined, undefined, key, frame);
```

you can then paste onto a game object using

```
rt.draw(gameObject, x, y);
```

or a group using

```
rt.draw(group, x, y);
```

see the full documentation for this [here](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/rendertexture/)